# How does MassTransit consumes CPU

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, masstransit

I am using https://masstransit.io/ library and sending 2000 messages uses 100% CPU for 15 minutes in average.

First, I thought it was due to the job requested by the message, but then I have tried without any job and just sending 2000 messages gave the same result.

Is that normal ?
How does MassTransit consumes CPU ?

Messages were sent with Azure Function that called following method:

```
public async Task DoJob(string contextName, RequestDto request) 
{
    using var provider = _publishEndpointProvider.Build();
    var publishEndpoint = provider.Get();

    foreach (var reference in references)
    {
        await publishEndpoint.Publish(new ProcessMessage
        {
            MessageCorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            MessageCreationTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ContextName = contextName,
            StartDate = request.StartDate,
            EndDate = request.EndDate,
            Reference = reference
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Many thanks,
AK

Comment: Seems a bit extreme that it would take that long to send that many messages, then again - we don't know what backend you're using or how big the message is. So it might be normal for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't await every single call to publish in a loop, you're basically creating a massive wait for the broker to acknowledge the message. That's a lot of dead time doing nothing but waiting on the broker.
2. No clue what's behind your `Build` function, but I know it can't be good. In fact, I really know it can't be good. It can be terrible in fact. I'd suggest using the [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction/blob/master/src/Sample.AzureFunction/SubmitOrderHttpFunction.cs) as a guideline of how to publish messages using MassTransit in an Azure Function.

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I will test those and share results.